# String Format for numbers

Tags: python

```
def print_formatted(n):
    for i in range(1,n+1):
       print(str(i)+' '+str(oct(i)[2:])+' '+str(hex(i)[2:])+' '+str(bin(i)[2:]))
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    print_formatted(n)
```

The question is to print octal hexa and more type of number from a given number using loop. I am getting the same numbers but I don't know how to make the "SPACE" required in the binary number (can be seen in the pic in last column)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVRhm.png

Comment: Let me just say that this is a **really bad** expected output. You solved the task correctly but now need to worry about aligning your output in a tabular manner which is not as easy as it sounds and entirely irrelevant to the actual problem being solved. You basically need to figure out the longest string you would print and then before actually printing "leftpad" / `ljust` the string.

Answer (score -1):

```
def print_formatted(number):

    width = len("{0:b}".format(number))

    for i in range(1, number + 1):
        print("{0:{w}d} {0:{w}o} {0:{w}X} {0:{w}b}".format(i, w = width))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    print_formatted(n)
```

Try the above one.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

```
from typing import List

def get_largest_number_size(lines: List[List[str]]) -> int:
    """Returns the size of the largest element/number in the lines to be printed"""
    nlargest = 0
    for line in lines:
        for element in line:
            nlargest = max(nlargest, len(element))
    return nlargest

def print_formatted(n: int) -> None:
    lines = []
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        line = [str(i), str(oct(i)[2:]), str(hex(i)[2:]), str(bin(i)[2:])]
        lines.append(line)

    nlargest = get_largest_number_size(lines)

    for line in lines:
        for i, element in enumerate(line):
            # align the numbers
            line[i] = element.rjust(nlargest)
        print(" ".join(line))
```

Example usage:

```
print_formatted(5)
```

outputs:

```
1   1   1   1
2   2   2  10
3   3   3  11
4   4   4 100
5   5   5 101
```